# Pronunciation of the chemical element lead

Tags: pronunciation

How is the chemical element [lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead) pronounced in British English and American English? This seems to be difficult to search, because of the verb lead. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead) lists

> lead
>   noun \ˈlēd\

but the audio pronunciation is `\liid\`.

Comment: \liid\ sounds more South African to me than either British or American.

Comment: *Lead* as a noun pronounced /li:d/ or \ˈlēd\ using MW symbols (long ee sound) is what you put on a dog's collar to stop it running off. It's directly related to the verb pronounced the same way.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong noun. Check the definition--that one says " leadership". The MW entry for the element, with the correct pronunciation \ˈled\, is listed further down the page. The transcription \ˈlēd\ matches the audio: "ē" is the symbol used in MW for the IPA sound /i/.

Comment: The MW gives the pronunciation of the chemical element further down the page (\ˈled\), under *lead 4*,and the audio matches it. If the dictionariy you are consulting doesn't specify a BrE pronunciation, you might want to check a dictionary published in... Britain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Lead" in the sense of the metal is pronounced as /lɛd/ (to rhyme with "bed") in both British and American English.

Comment: And there is no significant variation between AmE and BrE.

Comment: Indeed! I have made that addition to my answer to be explicit about it.